# Python SQLAlchemy create in_ on text Column

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I need a condition in sqlalchemy that allow me to use a list of ids stored in a TEXT column as a parameter for a `in_`. The ids are simply stored like `1,2,3,4`. I tried to use an `in_` but it's seems that a "list" stored in a TEXT column is not the right way to do.

This is what I've tried:

```
filters.append(and_(Organisation.id.in_(Session.list_id), Session.token == token))
```

That gives me this error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: in_() accepts either a list of expressions, a selectable, or an "expanding" bound parameter: Column('list_id', Text(), table=<MYTABLE>)
```

So I try to find a split to do something like:

```
filters.append(and_(Organisation.id.in_(Session.list_id.split(',')), Session.token == token))
```

But split, explode or every kind of dissociate function doesn't exist!

I try to use a more SQL way, but i always bump in the use of a function that doesn't exist!

```
filters.append(Organisation.id.in_(ds.query(Session.list_id).filter(Session.token == token)))
```

What is the best way to achieve this? My last idea is to create a table to store each id in single row, but it seems a little bit overkill for what i need. Or do it in a separate query.

Any hint will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What DBMS are you using? And the "overkill" approach you've thought about would be the proper normalized form, so if possible, go with it. Your list-like column violates the [first normal form](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form).

Comment: In my local environement i'm using sqlite but the prod going to be postgresql. I made an edit in my question to also propose too use a separate query. The "overkill" approach will add 2 mores tables because I have 2 differents lists of id in my Session table. If I can keep It more simple, it will be great. I don't want to do more insert for 2 new tables just to keep a couple of ids...

Comment: Are the ids just some ids, or do they refer to some other table in your database? If you do want to keep on using an array, in Postgresql you could do just that *and* use operators such as `= ANY`. SQLite does not support arrays, though.

Comment: It's a list of ids of tables in the database, it's why i want to use the in_. But those ids are defined in a user session and will be create/delete with the connexion. I think they are not such important to be keep in a relation table. How does it work for the "any", I'm not sure to understand how to use it in my case

Comment: Postgresql supports arrays, `<left> = ANY (<array expr>)` checks if any/some *array item* is equal to *left*. But SQLite does not support any of that. But still, you'd probably be better off using the properly normalized form. You'd possibly be able to leverage the ORM relationships in SQLAlchemy.

Comment: Ok thanks I put will give it a try after weekend if nothing "sqlite ready" comes out.

Comment: In relation to worrying about extra inserts, if your ids are what I think they are and you'll add the ORM relationships, you don't have to handle inserting to the association tables manually. You just assign / append / extend the list of related entities and the ORM relationship does the job for you. I'm fairly certain that this is a bit of an XY problem.